# local variables not used (pascal)

Tags: variables, pascal

It keeps saying that i,cont and divisor are not being used and I cant figure out why, everthing is assinged and used at some point.

I can compile it using the command prompt but it doesnt display what it should as a result it shows simbols, and if I try another compiler it just shows the local variable not used message it is not an error it just says: note Local variable "i" not used

Here´s the code

```
program tarea1;

var 

n,m,i,divisor,cont: integer;

begin

readln(n);
readln(m);


if (n<1) or (m<n) then
end.

i:=n;

for i to m do
  begin 

divisor:=2;

while (sqrt(i) >= divisor) and (i mod divisor <> 0)  do
divisor:=divisor + 1;

if (divisor > sqrt(i)) then
writeln(i': es primo')

else

   begin

for i to (i div 2) do
     begin

divisor:= 2;
cont:= 0; 
write(i':');

repeat
  if i mod divisor = 0 then
      begin

write(' divisor ');
divisor:=succ(divisor);
cont:=succ(cont);

until cont = 6;
writeln();
             end;
        end;
    end;
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program is not as long as you seem to think.

Around line 14 the code is:

```
if (n<1) or (m<n) then
end.
```

This "end." is the end of the source code - everything after that is not part of your program!

If you want to terminate your program if n is less than 1 or m is less then m then you should write

```
if (n<1) or (m<n) then
    exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn´t know that that fixed that problem

Comment: @R.FALLEN Then you'd accept the answer of Thomas by ticking V